# Typedef array referencing?

Tags: c++, arrays, graph, typedef

Hello I have a question regarding the usage of typedef in C++. I am trying to create my own graph class where I can perform DFS and BFS. I have attached what I have for the class so far. But every time I try to compile I run into certain errors that I just do not know how to fix. I am sure the error has something to do with the variable vertexList that I use to hold all the vertices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>    


class myGraph{
    public:
        typedef struct Vertex{
            char label;
            bool visited;
        }Vertex;
        myGraph(int);
        void AddVertex(char);
        void addEdge(int, int);
        int adjUnvisited(int);
        void displayVertex(int);
        void dfs();    

    private:
        Vertex* vertexList;
        int** adjMatrix;
        int size;
        int vertices;
        int count;    

};    

myGraph::myGraph(int size){
    count = 0;
    size = size;
    vertices = size;
    vertexList = new Vertex[vertices];
    adjMatrix = new int*[size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++){
        adjMatrix[i] = new int[vertices];
    }    

    for(int i=0; i<vertices; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<vertices; j++){
            adjMatrix[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }    



}    

void myGraph::AddVertex(char label){
    Vertex* myVertex = new Vertex();
    myVertex->label = label;
    myVertex->visited = false;
    vertexList[count++] = myVertex;    

}    

void myGraph::addEdge(int a, int b){
    adjMatrix[a][b] = 1;
    adjMatrix[b][a] = 1;    

}    

int myGraph::adjUnvisited(int index){
    for(int i=0; i<vertices; i++){
        if(adjMatrix[i][index]==1 && vertexList[i]->visited==false){
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}    

void myGraph::displayVertex(int index){
    std::cout << "Current vertex: " << vertexList[index]->label << std::endl;
}    

void myGraph::dfs(){
    std::stack<int> myStack;
    int temp = 0;    

    vertexList[temp]->visited = true;    

    myStack.push(temp);    

    int unvisitedVertex;    

    while(!myStack.empty()){
        unvisitedVertex = adjUnvisited[myStack.top()];
        if(unvisitedVertex!=-1){
            myStack.push(unvisitedVertex);
            displayVertex(unvisitedVertex);
            vertexList[unvisitedVertex]->visited = true;
        }else{
            myStack.pop();
        }
    }    

}
```

The error message that I get is this:

no viable overloaded '=' vertexList[count++] = myVertex;

Along with a note:

candidate function (the implicit copy assignment
      operator) not viable: no known conversion from 'struct Vertex *' to
      'const myGraph::Vertex' for 1st argument; dereference the argument with *
                struct Vertex{

And some other error messages which are (I'm sure these are very minor and I can figure them out):

member reference type 'struct Vertex' is not a
      pointer; maybe you meant to use '.'?
                if(adjMatrix[i][index]==1 && vertexList[i]->visited==false){

reference to non-static member function must be called
                unvisitedVertex = adjUnvisited[myStack.top()];

Now I am not sure what exactly I am doing wrong and was wondering if someone here could help me out.

Thank you very much for all your help!

Comment: Your private member `vertexList` is a list of concrete `Vertex` objects while you're trying to add a `Vertex` pointer to that array. Which is exactly what the error is saying.

Comment: Incidentally, instead of `typedef struct Vertex{ char label; bool visited; } Vertex;` you can just say `struct Vertex{ char label; bool visited; };`. Structs are automatically unqualified types in C++. (This is unrelated to your problem though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've declared `vertexList` as a pointer-to-`Vertex` - which is fair enough, since it's going to be an array. But that means that each element of that array is a `Vertex` structure - yet you're accessing each array element as though it was a pointer.

Either:

- Replace all the `->`s with `.`s and do something different in `AddVertex()`
- Declare `vertexList` as a `Vertex **` (like `adjMatrix`)